# How to select multiple checkboxes in a Drag event

Tags: java, android, android-layout

We have multiple checkboxes, as shown below:

[image]

We want the user to be able to select first checkbox for A,B,C, by him dragging over the checkboxes.
Is this possible in android?

Comment: Yes it's possible but  it would make a poor UX pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could do something like that.  You'd have to first start a drag operation and drag a view.  If you tried to do it with just your finger, it would be an exercise in gesture detection.  But dragging a view would be simple.

Using this tutorial as a guide - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html - you should be able to start a drag operation using a click listener on the view you want to drag. Then, as the dragged view enters the bounding boxes (you set up draglisteners on each) of a checkbox, you can set it to checked.